# Detect when element is less than 100px from top of window, change CSS

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make it so that when `div.projectsgrid` is < 100px from the top, jQuery will see if `div.selectedwork` has css background-color #ffffff. If not, it will set its background-color to #ffffff. Once the user scrolls back up and `div.projectsgrid` is more than 100px from the top, jQuery will remove the background color. I have the following code, which isn't working:

```
$(window).scroll(function(e){ 
    var el = $('.selectedwork'); 
    var top = $('#projectsgrid').offset().top;

    if ($(top) < 100 && el.css('background-color') != '#ffffff'){
        $(el).css({'background-color': '#ffffff'});
    }
    if ($(top) > 100 && el.css('background-color') == '#ffffff'){
        $(el).css({'background-color': ''});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use a class instead of looking at the background color. Also, your "projectgrid" is an ID and not a class. I also adjusted the distance to 200, as it seemed to look better.

This is how I would do it:

CSS

```
.bg-black { background-color: #000; }
```

Script

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
    var el = $('.selectedwork'),
        top = $('#projectsgrid').offset().top - $(document).scrollTop();
    if (top < 200 && !el.is('.bg-black')){
        $(el).addClass('bg-black');
    }
    if (top > 200 && el.is('.bg-black')){
        $(el).removeClass('bg-black');
    }  
});
```

Comment: This works! I was going to use a class, but I plan on animating the background so it will fade. So the offset().top wasn't calculating to the top of the browser, it was to the top of the whole document, thus you subtracted scrollTop? I'm a little bit confused.

Comment: Yes, `$('#projectsgrid').offset().top` is a constant. Only `$(document).scrollTop()` changes as you scroll the window (and it is the value of the top of the viewable page). So you can figure out how far form the top the project grid is from the top of the page by subtracting them.

Answer (score 4):

This should do it:

```
$(window).scroll(function(e) {
    var sw = $('.selectedwork'),
        pg = $('.projectsgrid'),
        diff = pg[0].offsetTop - window.pageYOffset;

    sw.css('background-color', diff < 100 ? 'yellow' : '');
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/SJDcS/2/

---

`[0]` and `?` are not related:

`[0]` is a convenient way to get the first DOM element from a jQuery object. In the above case, the jQuery object `pg` contains only one DOM element, so `pg[0]` will get that element. I retrieve the DOM element because the property `offsetTop` is a DOM element property and not a jQuery property. I guess `pg[0].offsetTop` and `pg.offset().top` return the same value.

`?` is part of the conditional operator of JavaScript. The conditional operator is a convenient method of setting two different values depending on a condition.

If statement:

```
if ( x > 10 ) {
    y = 'Yes';
} else {
    y = 'No';
}
```

Conditional operator:

```
y = x > 10 ? 'Yes' : 'No';
```

As you can see, the conditional operator is the better choice.

---

With color animation:

```
$(window).scroll(function(e) {
    var sw = $('.selectedwork'),
        pg = $('.projectsgrid'),
        diff = pg[0].offsetTop - window.pageYOffset;

    sw.animate({ backgroundColor: diff < 100 ? '#FFAAAA' : '#EEEEEE' }, 200);
});
```

Note: the [jQuery Color plug-in](http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery.color.js.txt) is required for this solution.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/SJDcS/4/

Comment: This also works, with less code. I've never seen `pg[0]` with `?`. How does that work?  Also, is there a way to fade it in instead of just setting the CSS?

Comment: Sliding won't really help much here. The #projectsgrid is always present, below the .selected work. I just need the bg of selected work to fade in. Or fade to a new class. Is there a way to use `?` with `sw.animate({ backgroundColor: "yellow" }, "slow");`

Comment: @steve Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/SJDcS/4/ You need to use the jQuery Color plug-in. Get it here: http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery.color.js.txt

Comment: IE ignores `$(window).scroll()`, use `$(document).scroll()` instead. Also, you can animate colors with jQuery UI (http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/#demo).

Comment: Hmm, ok maybe you're right... My IE9 was in compatibility mode and the animation was really really delayed.

Comment: @fudgey According to the [DOM 3 Events spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-scroll) the scroll event, when fired at the document object, must bubble to the window object. I would be surprised if IE violates this rule.