# How to check if div reaches top of page for each div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my current solution to check if a specific div reaches the top of the page, which i got from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/5279537/4671165

```
document.addEventListener("scroll", Scroll, false);

function Scroll() {
    var top = $('.element').offset().top - $(document).scrollTop();

    if (top < 150){
          var textvariable = $('.text').text();
     } 
}
```

But i want this to do something each time a different div reaches the top of the page, therefore i currently have

```
    var top1 = $('.element1').offset().top - $(document).scrollTop();
    var top2 = $('.element2').offset().top - $(document).scrollTop();
    var top3 = $('.element3').offset().top - $(document).scrollTop();

if (top1 < 150 && top2 > 150){
   var textvariable = $('.text1').text();
} 

if (top1 < 150 && top2 < 150 && top3 > 250){
    var textvariable = $(.text2').text();
} 

if (top2 < 150 && top3 < 250){
    var textvariable = $(.text3').text();    
}
```

However, this doesn't seem the most effective way but i can't figure out what is. Especially since i have more elements then just 3 in the project. So i am looking for a more effective way.

Comment: Create a fiddle, it would easy to help you from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a jquery solution

```
function ScrollStart() {

var scrolled = $(this).scrollTop();


/*filter current element at the top with a certain class & give it active class*/

$('.step').removeClass('activetext').filter(function() {
     return scrolled <= $(this).offset().top + $(this).height() - 50 && scrolled >= $(this).offset().top - 50;
}).addClass('activetext');

/* make exclusion for first element */

var boven = $('.first').offset().top - $(document).scrollTop();

if (boven > 0){     
   $('.first').addClass('activetext');
} 

/*make exclusion for last element*/

var bottom = $('.last').offset().top - ($('.last').height()/5) - $(document).scrollTop();

if (bottom < 150){
    $('.step').removeClass('activetext')
   $('.last').addClass('activetext');
} 
else{ 
    $('.last').removeClass('activetext')
}

    /* give variable 'text' the text of the active class & append it */

var text = $('.activetext .headertekst').text();
$('.dropbtn').empty();
$('.dropbtn').append(text);
    $('.dropbtn').append('<img src="images/downarrow.svg" galleryimg="no"></img>');
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I put this together using ES6.  I *believe* this should work.  It's been a while since I've used getBoundingClientRect() though.

```
var divs = document.querySelectAll('div');

document.addEventListener("scroll", Scroll, false);

function Scroll() {
    divs.forEach((memo,index) => {
        let divTop = memo.getBoundingClientRect().top;
        if (divTop <= 0) {
            var textvariable = $('.text' + index).text();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope [this](https://github.com/softwarespot/jquery-scrollspy) helps. It should be easier to use and it has a lot of bugs already fixed for you. It's a 1.82 kb file so there's not really much useless stuff into it if added.